# How to show $T$ is a continuous linear transform?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

If $\mathbb{M}$ is a closed linear subspace of a normed linear space $\mathbb{N}$, and if $T$ is the natural mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}/ \mathbb{M}$ defined by $T(x):=x+\mathbb{M}$, show that $T$ is a continuous linear transform for which $\left\|T\right\|\leq1.$

**Solution**

We know that $\left\|T(x)\right\|$ is defined as $\left\|T(x)\right\|$=$\left\|(x+\mathbb{M})\right\|$
=inf{$\left\|x+y\right\|:y\in \mathbb{M}$}.
It is easy to prove that $T$ is linear.
For showing that $T$ is continuous, we need to prove there exists some $k\geq0$ such that $\left\|T(x)\right\|\leqslant k\left\|x\right\|$.

- $\left\|T(x)\right\|$=$\left\|(x+\mathbb{M})\right\|$=inf{$\left\|x+y\right\|:y\in \mathbb{M}$}.
  I am unable to find some positive k for which $\left\|T(x)\right\|\leqslant k\left\|x\right\|$ holds.
  Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just compute $$\|Tx\|_{X/M} = \|x+M\|_{X/M} \leq \|x\|_X,$$simply because $0\in M$. So $k=1$ works and $\|T\|\leq 1$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.